# Is Trogdor attending the Burninating [Man] Festival this year?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

We have a [man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/man) tag, which has the following description:

> A man page (short for manual page) is online software documentation, serving as content for the man system, for an entity typically encountered in Unix or a Unix-like operating system. Such entities include computer programs (including library and system calls), formal standards and conventions, and even abstract concepts. A user may invoke a man page by issuing the man command.

This doesn't sound too definite.

Incidentally, we also have a [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual) tag, and it's not clear what the difference is supposed to be.

Questions on this are everything from "where can I find this manual?" to advice on how to write manuals in the first place (which isn't even on-topic here).

Can we burninate this (or at least make it a synonym of [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual))?

Comment: So are questions about writing manpages not on topic here then?

Comment: Also are questions *about* manpages not on topic here, then?

Comment: @Makoto that kind of buries the hatchet. You can ask about the manpage syntax ([which is fairly simple](https://linux.die.net/man/7/man)), not about the supposed content.

Comment: Manual is worse than man, with man you at least have something concrete. With manual, any manual goes.

Comment: A quick view of the first question page looks pretty good, not that many bad questions. I don't see a good reason to burninate this tag as-is, perhaps you could go over the burninate criteria to illustrate why it should be removed?

Comment: Can we please vote on the content of the question, not on the witty title alone...

Comment: @rene Don't I get at least *some* credit for wittiness here? ;)

Comment: While seeing the title, I was half hoping that there was some real burning man tickets to win (even if I don't really see link between the festival and SO, but anyway...). And a quarter hoping that this offer was not reserved for USA users...

Comment: @Pac0 the answer isn't any better in that regard ...

Comment: Shouldn't it be the Burninating [Man] Festival?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Yep, I agree :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> This doesn't sound too definite.

It doesn't come more definite then that. And if that now becomes a reason to remove a tag, not a single tag is safe.

As the *nix command is called `man` and most if not all documentation is written in man-pages `man` is a tool that is often used by programmers. With that fact alone questions about it are on-topic.

Only a small portion of the questions is not answered which is probably due to its 48 watchers. I consider this then to be one of the better curated tags.

Let's not make the life of 48 users that are providing answers miserable. The tag is not a crap magnet.

The tag can stay.

Comment: It would appear that I'm outvoted...

Comment: @EJoshuaS: You're not out-voted; you're simply not knowledgable about the subject matter. Not everyone knows about *NIX esoterica. There's no shame in that.

Comment: @NivolBolas It's almost too bad I ended up being incorrect - it made for a nice pun in the title.