# Oh [man], read the freakin' [manpage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Currently, the tags [man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/man) and [manpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manpage) have a similar description and similar questions, both dealing with, well, [man pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

Should the tags be synonymized in one way or another?

For reference, while typing this I'm being suggested [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375926/is-trogdor-attending-the-burninating-man-festival-this-year), which is about merging [man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/man) with [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual), so actually not the same thing and probably not a good idea.

Comment: Unless you are directly writing a manual page (please, don't do this, use a helper transcriber), I don't see much point on any of these tags.

Comment: While I don't expect them to be wildly popular, I think it absolutely make sense to have a tag for this. Some people may prefer to write manpages directly for whatever reason, and even with a transcriber you may have questions about how to get your resulting manpage right. And there are also questions about the content of existing manpages (e.g. "what is the 'send queue' in the manpage of ioctl"). It should be just one tag though, and I'd also ditch `manual`.

Comment: @jdehesa "what is the 'send queue' in the manpage of ioctl" that's not a question about man, that's a question about ioctl, or more specifically the linux-kernel (I don't know which other have implemented this, you would have to consult the implementation manual of any piece of software that implemented those). Tags aren't supposed to read as titles or hashtags. The content of the manual have nothing to do with formatting one.

Comment: @Braiam But what if I'm writing a helper transcriber? ;)

Comment: @BenjaminW. In what language, what libraries, framework?

Comment: @Braiam I was just thinking that that would be a case where the tags make sense.